# How to update an aggregation with a new one on a regular basis?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregation

I have the following problem.
I aggregate my data by date, product category, and quantity. I need to add a new data point to the aggregation as soon as new data is written into the table.

The initial code is as follows, works as expected:

```
SELECT 
date AS day,
string_field_1 AS product,
SUM (quantity) AS quantity_total
FROM sales
JOIN product_type
    ON sales.product = product_type.string_field_0
GROUP BY day, product
ORDER BY day, product
```

My struggle is that I have two tables updated: the sales and product. The product may randomly change, so I have to check that table for updates and add aggregations of new data points from sales to my query.
To be honest, I have zero clue how to make this work. I've tried writing conditionals, but I am wrong all the time.

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: The query runs always with ball data, that are avalaible, so your gui would check all teh time if new data are available. and for that wiil query the database

Comment: and there are materialized views, hat would keep the result set always uptodate

Comment: @nbk, sure, I get that. But I imagine the following situation. Product A was assigned to product_type_1 in July, but starting from August, it is now assigned to product_type_2. Table Product_type does not have the assignment dates, only id and type. If it is changed, we won't know when, and the query will return the data for August as it was always like that. But what if I need to know the product_types for July? That's the question...

Comment: I understand your problem, but without the database structure be cause you would need a bridge table between those tables with start date so that you can get Th we type that was valid at the date and you need to join the actual product type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the basic design from a 1:n relationship to a n:m, which means there is a bridge table between sales and product_type

```
sales           sales_producttyp           product_type
--------        ----------------           -------------
sales_id        sales_id (fk)              tring_field_0
date            product (fk)
quantity        startdate
                enddate
```

Your choice of column nmes needs some improving, as it should be clear when seeing it what it means

So your query would change to:

```
SELECT 
    date AS day,
    string_field_1 AS product,
    SUM(quantity) AS quantity_total
FROM sales sa
JOIN sales_producttyp sp ON sa.sales_id = sp.sales_id AND date  BETWEEN strtdate AND enddate
JOIN product_type p
    ON sp.product = p.string_field_0
GROUP BY day, product
ORDER BY day, product
```

And of course when you insert the data into sales, you must also add a row in the bridge table

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, the bridge is where I went in the end.